# After a button is clicked/form submit, the CSS stylesheet doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, html, css

After the use button is clicked, the sources when I inspect the page show that the style.css page goes away, and no styles are applied. I can't figure out why this is happening.

My index.html page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500&family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <input type="text" placeholder="First name" class="fname">
        <input type="submit" value="Use" class="submit">


        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my app.js is this:

```
const useBtn = document.querySelector('.submit');
const reloadBtn = document.querySelector('.btn__reload')

document.body.style.fontFamily = "Roboto;"

useBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let person = document.querySelector('.fname').value;
    document.write(`<h2>It's ${person}'s turn!</h2>`)
    document.write(`<h4>How long will they live?</h4>`)
    let oldAge = `<p>${Math.floor((Math.random() * 10)+ 30)}</p>`
    document.write(oldAge)
    document.write(`<h4>What will be their yearly salary?</h4>`)
    let salary = `<p>${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}</p>`
    document.write(salary)
    document.write(`<h4>What will be their career</h4>`)
    const jobs = [ 'plumber', 'doctor', 'witch', 'president', 'trump supporter']
    let job =  Math.floor(Math.random() * jobs.length)
    document.write(jobs[job])
    redoBtn();

})

function redoBtn(){
    let tryAgain = document.createElement('button')
    document.body.appendChild(tryAgain)
    let buttonText = document.createTextNode('Try Again')
    tryAgain.appendChild(buttonText)
    tryAgain.addEventListener('click', function(){
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
    })
}
```

Any help is so appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your `document.write` is overwriting all your html, including your linked stylesheet.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write:

> Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open, which will clear the document.

If you really want to use `document.write`, you'll need to rewrite your stylesheet link into the new document. But it might be better to just replace the html of some container element on your page, like the `body` element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using document.write which overwrites your html you could try this approach:

```
    <input type="submit" value="Use" class="submit">

    <!-- add new div to show the result -->
    <div id="result"></div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
```

And in the click event:

```
useBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let person = document.querySelector('.fname').value;
    let res = document.getElementById('result');
    
    res.innerHTML = "<h2>It's "+person+"'s turn!</h2>";
    // add further information to innerHTML here
    // hide input fname and submit button

    redoBtn();
})
```